# How to handle global objects / tests influencing other tests in Jest

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

Some of my tests in my React Native project affect global objects. These changes often affect other tests relying on the same objects.

For example: One test checks that listeners are added correctly, a second test checks if listeners are removed correctly:

```js
// __tests__/ExampleClass.js
describe("ExampleClass", () => {
    it("should add listeners", () => {
        ExampleClass.addListener(jest.fn());
        ExampleClass.addListener(jest.fn());

        expect(ExampleClass.listeners.length).toBe(2);
    });
    it("should remove listeners", () => {
        const fn1 = jest.fn();
        const fn2 = jest.fn();
        ExampleClass.addListener(fn1);
        ExampleClass.addListener(fn2);

        expect(ExampleClass.listeners.length).toBe(2);

        ExampleClass.removeListener(fn1);

        expect(ExampleClass.listeners.length).toBe(1);

        ExampleClass.removeListener(fn2);

        expect(ExampleClass.listeners.length).toBe(0);
    });
});
```

The second test will run fine by itself, but fails when all tests are run, because the first one didn't clean up the ExampleClass. Do I always have to clean up stuff like this manually in each test?

It seems I'm not understanding how the scope works in Jest... I assumed each test would run in a new environment. Is there any documentation about this?

Other examples are mocking external libraries and checking if the mocked functions in them are called correctly or overriding `Platform.OS` to ios or android to test platform-specific implementations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I can see, the scope of a test is always the test file. For now I changed my code to have a `beforeEach` callback that mainly calls `jest.resetAllMocks()` and resets `Platform.OS` to its default value.

> Fast and sandboxed
>
> Jest parallelizes test runs across workers to maximize performance. Console messages are buffered and printed together with test results. Sandboxed test files and automatic global state resets for every test so no two tests conflict with each other.
>
> https://facebook.github.io/jest/